# Codeigniter Make URL SEO FRIENDLY

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, seo

My current URL is like:

```
www.hostname.com/get_city/
```

(this url is already shorten by using routes)
Here `get_city` is my method name and now **what i exactly want is**...

1)**remove** controller name from url

2)**pass selected city value** from dropdown and set in URL as a parameter

So,Required url is: `www.hostname.com/california` OR `www.hostname.com/newjersey`

NOTE:I know how to use routes but in such case how to make dynamic URL?!
**AND please don't give me direct reference of ellislab docs because i have already tried those things**

Comment: If you **have already tried those things**, instead of yelling this at folks trying to help you, *show them* what you have done.  That will help weed out people with those suggestions, and may reveal flaws in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic route in codeigniter:

try like this:

in your routes.php file copy and paste these codes:

```
require_once (BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/url_helper' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/text_helper' . EXT);
$db = &DB();

$query = $db -> get('news');
$result = $query -> result(); //result return all records
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row -> subject)));
    $route[$string] = "controller/news_details/$row->id";
}
```

so you can , change $string with any string that you want.

then try type new url and see Routes will work fine.

NOTE:.htaccess file must be removing index.php in url

hope this help.

Comment: He may not be using database routes.

Comment: i think , he want make dynamic URL!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the method "_remap".

Check the official documentation for more info about the behavior of the function:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config routes in application/config/routes.php

After existing routes add

```
$route['([a-z]+)'] = 'controller_name/method_name/$1';
```

But this overwrite all routes and before this route you need to declare all routes for you controllers

```
$route['product/:any'] = 'product/$1';
$route['catalog/:any'] = 'catalog/$1';
```

and after

```
// this route be used when previous routes is not suitables

$route['([a-z]+)'] = 'controller_name/method_name/$1';
```

DOCS:

http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/general/routing.html

CI2: [URI Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)

CI3: [URI Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)